# Protractor click fa fa-pencil button based on row text in ag-grid table

Tags: jasmine, protractor

please help me to click the fa fa-pencil button with respective its table row value, where the button is present in the ag-grid.
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IGf7.png) [UI-VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5PZg.png)
The below one is not worked for me

```js
  element(by.cssContainingText('div[role="row"] div.ag-cell-value', "lavanya@gmail.com"))
  .element(By.xpath("i[class='fa fa-pencil']")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the `comp-id` attribute is unique. Have you tried that?

```
element(by.css('[comp-id="75"]'));
```

or by its `col-id`:

```
element(by.css('[col-id="email"]'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the issue is clicking the edit button and not text. I want to click the edit button on the basis of a text which presents in the row

Comment: do you know how many of those `<i>` buttons are there? you could target it directly using the index: `element.all(by.css('.fa.fa-pencil')).get(index);`

Comment: Yes, but we should not use index right it's not a proper way and same while it's dynamic if I add a row tomorrow the index will change that's why am asking for the scenario it should click that pencil button in the basis of test data = mail address